# Transistor latch

Tags: transistors, mosfet, 2n2222

[image: Schematic]

I've tried making multiple transistor latches and I'm able to get them working on the breadboard but everytime I try putting it on a prototype board the resistors changed their value. The one that acts up the most is made with two variable resistors to make 640k it's a 500k and 200k and they test properly in the prototype board if their isolated but connected to the circuit they change I'm new to transistors so I'm probably overlooking something simple. Is it possible my resistor values are wrong? I'm using two 2n2222a and a ifr905 mosfet.

Comment: A diagram would be useful. 100's of kΩ are a bit larger than one commonly employs in BJT circuits.

Comment: i added the schematic

Comment: T2 and T3 are backwards - the emitter of an NPN transitor should be the most negative terminal - the arrow points in the direction of conventional current flow.

Comment: I swapped it around with the emitter connected to ground and the button is still unresponsive

Comment: Should I go with another design? I just need it to power a Arduino and let it turn itself off and I've been fighting this for months

Comment: the resistors changed their value? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @KaliBot I'm just reading this and it looks like what you are trying to do is coming out in drips and drabs. What exactly do you really want? Is this about powering an Arduino, perhaps via a manual switch or by an external signal (not sure which or both) but where the Arduino can turn itself off when it wants to? I'm still confused. Maybe it's just me and the time of night.

Comment: If you measure resistors in a circuit, the resistance will be the resistor AND something in parallel with it.